# Drupal view filtering with one taxonomy term and using an argument to add another filter

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy, drupal-exposed-filter

Ok so I'm probably being exceptionally retarded.. I'm building a 2-column display in drupal listing cars, which are content type product. We have 2 taxonomy vocabularies, brand and colour. One block will display colour orange, and the other will display colour blue. I'm trying to pass the argument (eg Ford) through to the view so that it'll display only Orange fords or Blue fords (one block view does orange, one block view does blue) but as soon as I pass an argument through no data is returned. Checking the data, I have content that will match. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create two displays, for one display `add a filter : content-color = Orange` for the other display `add a filter : content-color = Blue`

For both the displays add `an argument : taxonomy-termid = term_id_for_Ford` and it should work.

If this doesn't work show us the export code, may be that will help.